# Some issue about Paw3

Tags: paw-app

After trying [Paw3](https://paw.cloud) for a while, I found it's really amazing, but I have some little issue about the operation:

1. How can I bulk edit HTTP headers instead of editing in a table one by one?
2. How can I fold some of the `JSON text` code when response is too long?
3. When I search in the response, is there any way to show the number of the matches?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the kind words about Paw!

Unfortunately, none of the 3 things you've asked are already implemented.

> 1. How can I bulk edit HTTP headers instead of editing in a table one by one?

There's no ability to bulk-edit headers yet. Instead, we recommend users to [use environment variables as reusable presets](https://paw.cloud/docs/environments/environments-reusable-presets). We'd like to later add a batch-edit feature.

> 2. How can I fold some of the JSON text code when response is too long?

There's no way to fold JSON texts yet. You could use the regular JSON tree if you need to fold items. Same here, it's something we'd like to add to the text too.

> 3. When I search in the response, is there any way to show the number of the matches?

Not displayed. It would be easy to add though. I take note :)